# Open form results in new resized window

Tags: javascript, forms, popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitWindow() {
    ..
    // URL, name and attributes
    window.open('http://isivmwebtest.isolutionsinc.com/ComparativePricing/Content/PriceLookup.aspx','windowNew','width=300, height=300');
    return true;
}
</script>
<div class="form-outer">
<div class="resource-form">
<h3>FREE National Price-Look Up Tool</h3>
<h4>Powered by ComparativeHospitalData.com</h4>
<form action="http://isivmwebtest.isolutionsinc.com/ComparativePricing/Gateway.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="return submitWindow()">
<input type="hidden" name="RemoteAction" value="PriceLookup" />
<strong>Enter HCPCS Code(s)</strong><br />
<input onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" name="codes" value="XXXXX or XXXXX,XXXXX or XXXXX-XXXXX" /><br /><br />
<strong>Enter HCPCS Description</strong><br />
<input onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" name="desc" value="partial name okay" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
<span style="font-size:0.8em;font-style:italic;padding-top:10px;">*Search will lead you away from this site.</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I want this form to display the results in a popup window that's pretty small. I have tired many methods without any success. Right now I am using some Javascript to get it to work, but it still doesn't seem to do anything. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other parameters you can pass in the specs parameter besides width and height. See here. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

You can remove the title bar, status bar, etc to make it smaller.

Try:

```
window.open('http://isivmwebtest.isolutionsinc.com/ComparativePricing/Content/PriceLookup.aspx','windowNew','width=300,height=300,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no');
```

Answer (score 0):

This hidden field "RemoteAction" is required for popup to redirect the page to PriceLookup.aspx. That is the reason your popup is not showing the correct page.